# What was the 100th Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that according to the [main SE site](https://stackexchange.com/), there's 110 SE sites. Which one was the 100th site?

Comment: Well, many of those sites are in beta, do you really want to count beta sites?  Also note there have been a number of sites to be in beta and then end up being closed.

Comment: @Servy Good point, I think. The 'hundredth site' could actually change as older beta sites get removed too, I think. (Although one could still answer this historically, counting the deleted ones.) Hmm... how many graduated sites are there, anyway?

Comment: You planning a party? ;)

Comment: @Lix: Truthfully, I'm wondering if I missed one...

Comment: I count 41 graduated, 69 beta.

Comment: http://gamification.stackexchange.com is in private beta thus not listed in the [all sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#newest). So This makes 68 public beta sites and 42 graduated. @Andrew FYI as well. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That makes sense. 68 public, 1 private, 42 graduated, and 1 Area 51. Together is 110.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto wait... something is still weird. According to [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched), only 35 are launched. So we have a gap of 6 sites! (excluding area51)

Comment: OK, found one - http://patents.stackexchange.com/ was not launched through Area51 thus listed in All Sites but not in Area51. 5 more to go! :/

Comment: Oh, Patents, Math Overflow, Super User, Stack Overflow, MSO, and Server Fault, I bet are the 6.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto right on spot! So 42 it is.

Comment: At which point should a site count as existing? Proposed? Defined? Private beta launch? Public beta? Graduated? If it's public beta, I think the "100th oldest currently existing site" is the best we can get.

Comment: Definitely not proposed/defined. Private beta is the start point for a site. There isn't a great way of going back beyond that, but there is a few clues to older. I'm curious what others'll have to say on the matter.

Comment: You guys missed Stack Apps (since you *are* counting Area 51)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's see how many closed sites we can add to the list. There are [6 well known closes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/) that happened some time ago. Smugmug was also closed, started Feb 8, 2012. [Artificial Intelligence](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/) was probably the first closure. Also closed early on is [Gadgets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/). There was a few other briefly lived ones as well, but I'm going to try to not count ones that never left private beta. All in all, I count 10 known (To me, with searching) site closures. That means the real 100th site was up a bit, that'd put it at Genealogy & Family History.

Comment: Were any of those closed beta sites created after Robotics?

Comment: Robotics was 1 year 1 month ago, none of them were after Robotics.

Comment: Don't forget [Gadgets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/)

Answer (score 5):

taking all currently listed sites, sorted from oldest (https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest),  taking the 100th element (`$(".lv-item")[99]`), yields the answer:

100th .. 103rd oldest currently existing sites ([excluding private betas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204313/what-was-the-100th-stack-exchange-site/204315#comment652528_204313) and area51) are these sites with the same age:

- [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)
- [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/)
- [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta (thanks @PearsonArtPhoto for the link) gives their age in greater precision and disambiguates this site as the oldest of these four, and thus the 100th oldest currently existing site:

## [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The 100th oldest site is not the 100th site to be created.

Comment: @Servy how come it is not?

Comment: See [my earlier comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204313/what-was-the-100th-stack-exchange-site/204315?noredirect=1#comment652504_204313).  You aren't taking into consideration all of the sites that were created and then later removed.  The 100th oldest living person on Earth is not the 100th person in to be created.

Comment: @Servy I am aware of this difference. I think this is the closest we can get.

Comment: So it's impossible to know what sites have been created and then deleted?  That information is lost forever?  Or do you just mean that you can't find it in 10 seconds of looking.

Comment: @Servy do you have a better source of information? If you do, I will retract my answer

Comment: I know that this answer isn't correct, that doesn't mean that I know what answer *is* correct.  Me not knowing the real answer doesn't make this any more appropriate.

Comment: Network Engineering is the oldest of those (http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)